# How to specify a better type when destructuring

Tags: typescript

I've been adding a type to functions lately. But it feels too messy and I don't think it's the right way to specify the type. Is there a better way to specify the type?

This is an example.

```
const foo = ({id, name, agreement}
: {id: number | undefined; name: string | undefined | agreement: boolean | undefined}): string 
=> {
 // something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're ok with implicit `undefined`s be passed in (eg, if `foo({ name: 'bob' })` is ok, rather than being forced to do `foo({ name: 'bob', i: undefined, agreement: undefined })`, the first thing you could do is make the properties optional:

```
const foo = ({id, name, agreement}: {i?: number; name?: string, agreement?: boolean }): string => {
 // something
}
```

If that's still to combersome, you can define the type ahead of time:

```
interface Options {
  i?: number; 
  name?: string, 
  agreement?: boolean 
}

const foo = ({id, name, agreement}: Options): string => {
  // something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first example. But Webstorm shows me a warning meassage, and I ignored it.